# Python lambda based on condition in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I need to add an indicator column to my dataframe that flags user with promo code (1 if on promo else 0 ). I need to look at two columns and see if any promo code exist under either of col_promo_1, col_promo_2. This is the code I'm using but it returns Nan value:

```
df['promo_ind'] = df[['col_promo_1', 'col_promo_2']].apply(lambda x: 1 if x is not None else 0)
```

However, when I use the code with only one column for example col_promo_1, the result is accurate. Any thoughts on how can I get this fixed?

Comment: Can we have some sample data to work with?

Comment: Assuming non existent values are `None`, `df['col_promo_1'].notna() | df['col_promo_2'].notna()` will be the mask for all the rows that have a promo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new column:

```
df['promo_ind'] = 0
```

You can build a mask and use it to set the values in the correct places:

```
df.loc[df['col_promo_1'].notna() | df['col_promo_2'].notna(), 'promo_ind'] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to your approach, let's assume you have the below example DataFrame (`df`) with two columns (`promo1` and `promo2`) and the goal is to indicate promo status in a third column, if a user is on either promo1 or promo2.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'promo1': [0, 1, 0, 1], 'promo2': [0, 0, 1, 1]})
```

The line below, creates a third column, checks the two existing columns at every row and calculates the corresponding promo status accordingly. (The issue with the posted code is that "x" takes columns in the DataFrame one by one, although you want to take rows and check them. The fix is to set attribute `axis=1` for `apply()` method.)

```
df['promo_ind'] = df[['promo1', 'promo2']].apply(lambda row: 0 if (row['promo1']==0 and row['promo2']==0) else 1, axis=1)
```